# WPA PSK to WPA EAP PSK roaming

Tags: wifi, wpa2-psk, eap-psk

Would clients (iPhone, android, whatever) roam seamlessly from an AP using WPA-PSK to an AP using WPA-EAP-PSK (with PEAP passthrough setup) if the same PSK was used and valid on both APs (AP1 and AP2 radius)?

Further elaboration:

1) I would like to set up AP1 to use normal wpa2 psk. A user connects and types in their passphrase to log on.

2) I would then like to set up AP2 to use EAP. But I don't want the user to type in a username and password, I just want their passphrase to work.

Can AP2 / its radius be set up so that it authenticates the users passphrase without a need for username and password and to just let them on so they continue roaming seamlessly?

Basically, on our network, some APs have a 'hard coded' passphrase that we want to add to our database and be able to let them on other EAP APs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

If certificate its the same, WPA-PSK without EAP uses key and not certificate. Shoud run without problems.. mechanism are both same but difference in certificate and user and password added for more security. WPA-PSK are Encryption method and EAP add just user and password to. In other words.. EAP its designed for a Corporative Networks that require much security.

Comment: Thanks Gus... not sure if I understand.. I've updated my query above i hope it makes more sense..